# CSS: Dynamically generated aspect ratio, that fills the height of the container, but maintains the desired aspect ratio & never overflows the viewport

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

Unfortunately, I keep asking the wrong question… I'm trying to create a dynamically resized image that never overflows the viewport in either direction and keeps it aspect ratio. the code that was suggested to me by user:10867454 works perfectly, if I only have one article in the container. However, my preferred design includes multiple articles (images) of different aspect ratios.

Ultimately the problem seems to be that the article is being resized by a percentage of the viewport and not what I think I'm looking for which is the article should resize based on available space within the container (the container will be resized based on a % of the viewport) but the image should adhere to the desired aspect ratio and fill the available height of the container.

I've tried to adapt the calculation, but I can't seem to figure out how to change it or place it on the correct element.
I think that this is what I am looking, but have absolutely no idea how to do it:
--varWidth: should maintain the desired aspect ratio;
--varHeight: should be 100% of available container height;

And (If possible)

The --varWidth and --varHeight on any one image should never be greater then some % of the viewport.

You can see the problem in the second image where the article height is being set by the –-varHeight: 80vh; The first image is what I’m trying to achieve.

As an FY I the articles will never overflow the X axis, because the width of the container is being calculated vie JavaScript (And is greater then 100% of the viewport) and the images all have the same height of 950px.

If this is even possible, I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance - CES

[image: This is what I'm trying to do]

[image: This is the problem]

```css
 .contentContainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding: min(4vh, 3.5vw);
        background: hsl(0 0% 0%);
    }

    .pageDefault {
        display: flex;

        justify-content: center;

        width: 100%;
        height:auto;

        background: hsl(0 0% 10%);
    }

    /*#endregion */

    
    /*#region Article
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .pageDefault article {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    /*#region Article Aspect Ratios - (Defaults)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    .pageDefault .aspectRatio1x1 {
        --varAspectRatio: calc( 1 / 1);
        --varCalcHeight: min(calc(var(--varWidth) / var(--varAspectRatio)), var(--varHeight));
        width: calc(var(--varCalcHeight) * var(--varAspectRatio));
        height: calc(var(--varCalcHeight));

        background-color: red;
    }

    .pageDefault .aspectRatio3x2 {
        --varAspectRatio: calc( 3 / 2);
        --varCalcHeight: min(calc(var(--varWidth) / var(--varAspectRatio)), var(--varHeight));
        width: calc(var(--varCalcHeight) * var(--varAspectRatio));
        height: calc(var(--varCalcHeight));
    }

    .pageDefault .aspectRatio2x3 {
        --varAspectRatio: calc( 2 / 3);
        --varCalcHeight: min(calc(var(--varWidth) / var(--varAspectRatio)), var(--varHeight));
        width: calc(var(--varCalcHeight) * var(--varAspectRatio));
        height: calc(var(--varCalcHeight));
    }

    .pageDefault .aspectRatio4x3 {
        --varAspectRatio: calc( 4 / 3);
        --varCalcHeight: min(calc(var(--varWidth) / var(--varAspectRatio)), var(--varHeight));
        width: calc(var(--varCalcHeight) * var(--varAspectRatio));
        height: calc(var(--varCalcHeight));
    }

    .pageDefault .aspectRatio3x4 {
        --varAspectRatio: calc( 3 / 4);
        --varCalcHeight: min(calc(var(--varWidth) / var(--varAspectRatio)), var(--varHeight));
        width: calc(var(--varCalcHeight) * var(--varAspectRatio));
        height: calc(var(--varCalcHeight));
    }

    /*#endregion */


    .pageDefault .imgMain,
    .pageDefault .imgOther {
        object-fit: contain;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        border: 2px solid hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .25);

    }

    .pageDefault .imgMain {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="contentContainer">
        <main id="idMainContent" class="pageDefault">
            <article class="aspectRatio1x1">
                <figure class="">
                    <picture class="">
                        <img class="imgMain" src="../../images/portfolio/alt1-1x1.jpg" />
                    </picture>
                    <figcaption>xxxxxx</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </article>

            <article class="aspectRatio3x2">
                <figure class="">
                    <picture class="">
                        <img class="imgMain" src="../../images/portfolio/mainColor.jpg" />
                    </picture>
                    <figcaption>xxxxxx</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </article>
        </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're gonna need JS for this.

Comment: ‘The width of the container is being calculated by JavaScript’. Could you show us that code?

Comment: In the code above I'm not to use any javascript... However after another 2 days of trying to accomplish a pure css solution, I'm most likely go to abandon that and move on to a vanilla JavaScript solution. - CES